# BODLEVEL Fuse Coding

Tags: atmega, fuses, brownout

I'm using ATmega1280, and I have a question about this BOD table:
[image: BODLEVEL Fuse Coding]
what is exactly the meaning of "Min. Vbot" and "Max. Vbot"?

Comment: The range for the brown out detection is between Min and Max.

Comment: so below which level I'll guarantee to get the reset?

Comment: You could get a reset below max Vbot but you’re guaranteed to get a reset below min Vbot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the exact BOD voltage is a little imprecise and can vary within those limits. Take the strictest limit into consideration considering your implementation.

For example, if MCU is directly on battery and with BOD=1.8V, it will go into reset at some voltage between 1.7V and 2.0V (same voltage every time for the same MCU, but different for different MCUs, all between 1.7V and 2.0V), and you should consider 2.0V your real BOD voltage as you don't want to have half devices function at V=1.9V and half not. You aim for guaranteed predictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The ATMega 1280 has a brown out detection which could be configurated with some fuse bits. The voltage for brown out reset is not accurate, so you had select a range:

e.g.  2,5 ... 2,9 V

> BODLEVEL 2:0 101
> Typical Brown Out Voltage: 2,7V
> Min. Bown Out Voltage: 2,5 V (The chip is guaranteed to reset below this voltage)
> Max. Bown Out Voltage: 2,9 V (Below this voltage you could get a reset)